# Airflow HiveOperator Result Set

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, airflow

I'm new to both Airflow and Python, and I'm trying to configure a scheduled report.  The report needs to pull data from Hive and email the results.

My code thus far:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.hive_operator import HiveOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
    'email': ['email@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 3,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(hours=2)
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='hive_report',
    max_active_runs=1,
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='@once')

query = """
    #query goes here
"""

run_hive_query = HiveOperator(
    task_id="fetch_data",
    hql=query,
    dag=dag
)
```

I'm pretty sure I need to add an EmailOperator task to send the results, as this only seems to be configured to email on failure or retry.

My question is this: what does the Hive operator do with the result set?  What is the best way to pass the result set from one task to another?

Comment: `run_hive_query` should probably store the result set in a directory something like `to_be_emailed` while another downstream task would fetch that report, email it and move it to say `report_emailed` folder.  Just a thought.

Comment: It doesn't seem that HiveOperator return anything in execute: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/hive_operator.py#L104

You might try use hivehooks to get the result and put your result in PythonOperator: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/hive_hooks.py#L167

Answer (score 0):

Think you will also need to add a Hive Connection ID (The ID of the Airflow connection to use for connecting to the Hive database) as a paramater within the HiveOperator, so that Airflow can connect to your database:

```
run_hive_query = HiveOperator(
task_id="fetch_data",
hql=query,
hive_cli_conn_id='my_conn_id'
dag=dag
```

)

[HiveOperator arguments](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.9/_api/airflow/operators/hive_operator/index.html)